# Trying to make a searchable menu with individual routes

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

So I am making this Ionic 5 application and have created a searchable list that searches through and displays an array that is created in javascript. I am wondering, how would I go about making each of these items (when clicked) route to an their own respective pagse on the application? I really can't figure it out and can't find any resources surrounding this. Thank you so much. Below is my Javascript and Html.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-icon
      class="arrowback"
      name="arrow-back"
      routerLink="/home"
      routerDirection="back"
    ></ion-icon>
    <ion-title>Search</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar animated (ionInput)="getTopics($event)"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let topic of topics" (click)="navigateToDetails()">

      {{ topic }}  
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.page.scss'],
})
export class SearchPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.generateTopics();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

   topics: string[];

  generateTopics() {
    this.topics = [
      'Sophie Skirt - Gold',
      'Sophie Skirt - Red',
      'Jackie Top - Green ',
      'Some Random Dress',
      'What is hybrid application and why.?',
      'Procedure to remove back button text',
      'How to reposition ionic tabs on top position.',
      'Override Hardware back button in cordova based application - Ionic',
      'Drupal 8: Enabling Facets for Restful web services',
      'Drupal 8: Get current user session',
      'Drupal 8: Programatically create Add another field - Example',  
    ];
  }

  getTopics(ev: any) {
    this.generateTopics();
    let serVal = ev.target.value;
    if (serVal && serVal.trim() != '') {
      this.topics = this.topics.filter((topic) => {
        return (topic.toLowerCase().indexOf(serVal.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }

  navigateToDetails(){


    this.router.navigate(['trialsearch']);
  }

}
```